# IndexError: string index out of range in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

Could someone help me out with what is going wrong and what I can do to fix it?

> File "C:/Users/rawaa/raw/untitled2.py", line 246, in disp_message
>       str02= str02 + str01[single]
>
> IndexError: string index out of range

```
def disp_message(val01, file_name):

    f = open(file_name,'r')

    data = f.readlines()

    f.close()
    str01 = str(data[0])
    str02 = ' '

    for each in val01:
        #print each

        for single in each:

            #print single

            str02= str02 + str01[single]
            str02 = str02 + ' '

    print("the hidden message in the data is:")

    print(str02) 
    print("\n\npress 1. to see hidden data visualisation or  ctrl+c to terminate")

    cho = raw_input()

    if cho == '1':

        print(show_data(str01,1,val01))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and edit your question with a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

you didn't specify the range of length of each, you should do maybe :

```
for each in val01:
    #print each

    for single in range (len(each)):

        #print single

        str02= str02 + str01[single]
        str02 = str02 + ' '
```